# R - wired frequency redistribution when defining factors

Tags: r

I needed to define a factor and a wired redistribution of values appeard?!

First a vector is defined, with clear frequencies. Then a factor is defined, with labeling to and the frequencies change -- count both at all outputs, and observe the new order of elements.

First question: I want to decide this "ranking order" (i.e. `"Xanax"`, `"Felax"`, `"Relax"`) therfore factoring, (needed to specify the order for a ggplot inside a dataframe). So how to maintain the initial element order and the initial element frequencies?

Second question: WTF is that? It is totally inconsistent, or am I missing something?

```
(names <- c(rep("Xanax",5), rep("Felax",3), rep("Relax",4)))

 [1] "Xanax" "Xanax" "Xanax" "Xanax" "Xanax" "Felax" "Felax" "Felax" "Relax" "Relax" "Relax" "Relax"


(names <- factor(names, labels=c("Xanax","Felax","Relax")))

 [1] Relax Relax Relax Relax Relax Xanax Xanax Xanax Felax Felax Felax Felax
Levels: Xanax Felax Relax
```

Comment: You need to define the levels; ie `(names1 <- factor(names, levels=c("Xanax","Felax","Relax"),  labels=c("Xanax","Felax","Relax")))`

Comment: eg. Look at the factor levels when they are not explicitly defined `levels(factor(names))` (alphabetical). You then assigned labels incorrectly over these.

Comment: @user20650 thank you :) a new lesson for today: `labels =/= levels`. Have a nice day! Please add the comment as an answer. I will rate and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour comes from not defining the levels of the factor - good practice to explicitly define these.

```
(names1 <- factor(names, levels=c("Xanax","Felax","Relax"), 
                               labels=c("Xanax","Felax","Relax")))
```

In your example you assign labels c("Xanax","Felax","Relax"). But the order of the factor levels has not been defined so the default is alphabetical. (or as `?factor` help says "The default is the unique set of values taken by as.character(x), sorted into increasing order of x")

```
levels(factor(names))
#[1] "Felax" "Relax" "Xanax"
```

So you defined the factor 'Felax' the label 'Xanex'.